# where can i find libpython2.6.dylib on osx

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6, dylib

I'm looking for `libpython2.6.dylib` in my frameworks folder but for all my instals I can only find the `libpython2.7.dylib`.

I'm looking in 'System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.x'/lib .

I also notice that `libpython2.7.dylib` is actually just an alias for '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python', does this mean i can just make my own alias of the other 'Python' binaries that are on all the install directories?

Comment: Is Python 2.6 installed on the computer?

Comment: sure is, and it runs just fine

Comment: What's the version of the OS? What does `find /System/Library -name 'libpython2.*'` give you (type that in a terminal)? And it's a "VERY BAD IDEA" to mess with the `/System` python...

Comment: I only get the 2.7 dylib but i do see the `libpython2.6.a`

Comment: Did you install 2.6 yourself? Looks like you only have a static library.

Comment: @jdi On my system, a `ls /usr/lib/libpython2.*` gives a bunch of links to `/System/Library/...`, as expected. @jonathan topf : Where does your Python 2.6 comes from?

Comment: Yea if the OP does not see anything under `/usr/lib` then I assume it was a custom installed python2.6

Comment: this install came with Autodesk maya

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, it is stored under /usr/lib

Comment: Which you can find in 18GB. Press cmd+shift+.